# Was the design of the Republic Gunship influenced by the Mi-24 gunship?

Tags: star-wars

Seeing the great visual and operational similarities between the Russian [Mi-24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-24) helicopter gunship and the Republic Gunship seen in Star Wars, is there any actual design relation between the two?

Credible sources please.

Mi-24
[image]
[Image Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Russian_Air_Force_Mil_Mi-24P_Dvurekov-4.jpg)

Republic Gunship:
[image]
[Image Source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Low_Altitude_Assault_Transport/infantry)

Comment: Ehhhh, the similarity looks superficial.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Wookieepedia article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Low_Altitude_Assault_Transport/infantry/Legends) about the LAAT (Low Altitude Assault Transport, a.k.a the Republic Gunship), the answer is yes.

> "The Low Altitude Assault Transport/infantry (LAAT/i), often referred
>   to as the Republic attack gunship or Republic Gunship, was a
>   specialized gunship designed for aerial-based support and infantry
>   transportation."
>
> "**The LAAT was inspired by** real-world helicopter gunships, notably **the
>   Soviet (now Russian) Mil Mi-24 Hind helicopter gunship**."

Quote from the "Behind the Scenes" section of this other [Wookieepedia article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Low_Altitude_Assault_Transport):

> "**The design for the LAAT is largely based on that of the
>   Soviet/Russian Mi-24 Hind helicopter gunship**. The real-world gunship
>   also fulfills the dual role of ground attack and troop transport."

Comment: Un sourced quote is pure speculation. (Citation required)